# Flutter package record: input device not found

Tags: flutter, record

I downloaded the Flutter record 5.0.1 and ran the example in lib/. I got the following error:
flutter: wav supported: true
flutter: [] flutter: PlatformException(record, Failed to start recording, Input device not found., null)

I could not find where this error came from. How to fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with newer versions of the library, when used with an iOS simulator. The issue is already fixed in one dependency of the `record` package (`record_darwin`). Until the fix rolls out to the main version, you could add this manually to your `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
record: ^5.0.1
record_darwin: ^1.0.1-beta.1
```

Check out the related issue on GibHub: https://github.com/llfbandit/record/issues/222